# Perl XML::Twig - Extract field with similar tag

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm trying to parse a huge xml file with some similar tag. For the moment I can only parse the first tag and the first_child

Here is an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test version="1.0">
  <parameters/>
  <category name="z1" description="jobs currently running" count="30" timestamp="2010-01-16T14:24:31">
    <jobs name="ZEI018CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="147" threadId="202" pid="20521" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6102:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZUA002B" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="3375" threadId="194" pid="20521" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6102:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZZZ855" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="107" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZKA019CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="105" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZIN41B" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="3" threadId="104" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZIN198CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="103" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZHO060" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="61" threadId="102" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZEI019CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="101" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZEI013CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="99" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZEI011CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="98" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZEC007CL" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="0" threadId="97" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZEC001B" owner="A" type="auto" activityLevel="2" threadId="96" pid="20457" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6101:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/></category>
 <category name="z3" description="Batchjobs" count="0" timestamp="2015-01-16T14:24:31"/>
  <category name="z4" description="Interactivejobs jobs currently running in the system" count="498" timestamp="2015-01-16T14:24:31">
    <job name="CAS" owner="PA" type="interactive" activityLevel="0" threadId="14624" pid="23771" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6104:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="CR" owner="K" type="interactive" activityLevel="0" threadId="14586" pid="23771" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6104:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="MM" owner="DU" type="interactive" activityLevel="0" threadId="14570" pid="23771" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6104:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/>
    <job name="ZZ" owner="D" type="interactive" activityLevel="0" threadId="14568" pid="23771" vmName="Subs@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:6104:xxx" cpuUsage="0"/></category>
 <category name="services" description="The status" timestamp="2015-01-16T14:24:31">
    <service name="1" description="test1" port-status="up" thread-status="up"/>
    <service name="2" description="test2" port-status="up" thread-status="up"/>
    <service name="3" description="test3" port-status="N/A" thread-status="up"/>
    <service name="4" description="test4" port-status="up" thread-status="up"/></category></test>
```

For the first line I

```
my $parser = XML::Twig->new();
$parser->parsefile($xml);
```

For the first line I use

```
my $count = $parser->root->first_child('category')->att('count');
print $count;
```

For the next line this one

```
my $service = $parser->root->first_child('category')->first_child('job')->att('name');
print $service;
```

But I can't figure out how to get the port-status for a specific name like:

Or for a specific job name the type in the 2nd tag.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you reformat your question? there seems to be something deleted. Do you want the attributes of an element that has a specific attribute value? You can use a language similar to xpath with the `children` method.

Comment: I want to parse the fil and extract some field like port-status in service tag with for example name=1

Answer (score 1):

In your case the easiest is probably to use XPath to get what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig::XPath;

my( $service, $infile)= @ARGV;

my $t= XML::Twig->new()
                ->parsefile( $infile);

# get the service first, then the attribute
# note the \@'s, where Perl and XPath syntaxes collide
my @services= $t->findnodes( qq{//service[\@name="$service"]});
my $status= $services[0]->att( 'port-status');
print "status: $status\n";

# get it in one swell XPath query
my $status2= $t->findvalue( qq{//service[\@name="$service"]/\@port-status});
print "status: $status2\n";
```

If your XML file is really huge, and depending on what you need to do, there may be better alternatives though, using handlers. It's hard to tell from your example.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want something like this:

```
foreach ($parser->root->children('section[@name="1"]')){
  print join ", ", @{$_->atts}{'port-status', 'thread-status'}
}
```

with `children('section[@name="1"]')` you get all `section` elements whose `name` attribute is `1`.

Then you ask with the `atts` method for hash reference of that element and extract `port-status` and `thread-status`

**Edit**: sorry fixed, forgot that you'll get more than one with children.

Comment: this don't work Can't call method "atts" without a package or object reference